# how do I stop my landing page h1 and button from moving up everytime I add content underneath it?

Tags: html, css, layout, position, portfolio

Im trying to make a portfolio page and new to HTML and CSS
How do I stop my landing page h1 and button from moving upwards every time I start to add content to my About Me section. when I add content to my about me section or anywhere under my h1 and button they start shifting upwards and out of the screen if I add too much content. any advice would be very much appreciated.

and one more question how do I stop my landing page img img/jetpack.png from moving down the screen with me as I scroll I would like it to stay in place on the landing page.

Also please free to let me know if you spot any mistakes in my code and if there's anything you would do to improve it. all advice is appreciated greatly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/283305f487.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Omar's Portfolio</title>

  <!----- Navbar ----->

  <div class="navbar">
   <nav>
     <ul class="navbar-nav">

       <li class="logo">
    <img class="img-logo" src="img/Logo-White2.png" alt="My logo">
    </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="landing" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
          <span class="link-text">Home</span>
        </a>
        </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
          <span class="link-text">About Me</span>
        </a>            
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-screwdriver-wrench"></i>
          <span class="link-text">services</span>
        </a>        
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-folder-open"></i>
          <span class="link-text">Projects</span>
        </a>
        </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-id-card"></i>
          <span class="link-text">Contact</span>
        </a>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
          <span class="link-text"></span>
          </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
</head>

<body> 
    <section class="landing">

      <h1 class="landing-title">Welcome!</h1>
       <Button class="btn">Contact Me</Button>
       <img src="img/jetpack.png" alt="animated jetpack"

     </section>

  <div>
    <main class="about-me">
      <h2> Get To Know Me</h2>
        <p class="about-me-p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
        

    </main>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
:root { 
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Open sans';
}

* {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.6rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background-color:grey ;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #5A36AF;
}

main{
margin-left: 7rem;
margin-right: 7rem;
padding: 1rem;
}


/****** Navbar ******/
.img-logo {
margin-top: 1rem;
width: 8rem;
transition: width 350ms ease ;
} 

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  transition: width 350ms ease ;
}

.fa-brands {
  transition: width 3s ease;
}

.navbar-nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav-item {
  margin: 1rem;
}


.nav-item:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;;
}

.nav-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5rem;
}

.nav-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(1);
  transition: var(--transition-speed) ;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0) opacity(1);
  background: #9461B6;
  color:#EC8355 ;
  border-radius: 10%;
} 

.link-text {
  display: none;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.nav-link svg {
  min-height: 2rem;
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
}

.fa-solid {
color: white;
}

.fa-brands {
  color:white ;
}

.fa-brands,
fa-solid {
  transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.navbar:hover .fa-solid {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.navbar:hover .fa-brands {
  font-size: 4rem;
}
p {
  font-size: 30px;
}

/* Landing Page */

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.4;
  background-image: url(img/portfolio-bg4.png);
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover ;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.landing{
  max-width: 100% ;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0 2rem;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.landing-title{
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif; ;
  font-size: 7rem ;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.landing img {
  width: 22em;
  position: fixed;
  right: 18% ;
  top:10%;
  animation: floating ease 10s infinite ;
 
}

@keyframes floating{
  0%{
    transform: translate(10%, 0%);
  }
  25%{
    transform: translate(15%, 10%);
  }
  50%{
    transform: translate(10%, 8%);
  }
  75%{
    transform: translate(15%, 5%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate(10%, 0%);
  }
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 2rem 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: orange;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem ;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}
/* About Me */

h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.about-me {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
}












/* smaller screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.navbar {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5rem;
  }

  .logo {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .nav-link {
    justify-content: center;
  }

  main {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

/* larger screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.navbar {
  top: 0;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 100vh;
  }
.navbar:hover {
 width: 16rem;
  }
.navbar:hover .img-logo {
  width: 16rem;
  }

.navbar:hover .link-text {
  display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should close the image-tag properly, maybe this explains the unexpected behaviour of your page: `<img src="img/jetpack.png" alt="animated jetpack" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CSS code below:

```
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Open sans";
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.6rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: grey;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #5a36af;
}

main {
  margin-left: 7rem;
  margin-right: 7rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

/****** Navbar ******/
.img-logo {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 8rem;
  transition: width 350ms ease;
  position: fixed;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  transition: width 350ms ease;
}

.fa-brands {
  transition: width 3s ease;
}

.navbar-nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav-item {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.nav-item:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.nav-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5rem;
}

.nav-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(1);
  transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.nav-link:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0) opacity(1);
  background: #9461b6;
  color: #ec8355;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.link-text {
  display: none;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.nav-link svg {
  min-height: 2rem;
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
}

.fa-solid {
  color: white;
}

.fa-brands {
  color: white;
}

.fa-brands,
fa-solid {
  transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.navbar:hover .fa-solid {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.navbar:hover .fa-brands {
  font-size: 4rem;
}
p {
  font-size: 30px;
}

/* Landing Page */

h1 {
  position: fixed;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.4;
  background-image: url(img/portfolio-bg4.png);
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.landing {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.landing-title {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 7rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.landing img {
  width: 22em;
  position: fixed;
  right: 18%;
  top: 10%;
  animation: floating ease 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes floating {
  0% {
    transform: translate(10%, 0%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(15%, 10%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(10%, 8%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(15%, 5%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(10%, 0%);
  }
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 2rem 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: orange;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
}
/* About Me */

h2 {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.about-me {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
}

/* smaller screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 5rem;
  }

  .logo {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .nav-link {
    justify-content: center;
  }

  main {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

/* larger screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    top: 0;
    width: 8rem;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .navbar:hover {
    width: 16rem;
  }
  .navbar:hover .img-logo {
    width: 16rem;
  }

  .navbar:hover .link-text {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I have added `position: fixed;` to your logo and h1. This should solve the problem of the elements moving when you don't want them to.

Comment: unfortunately it hasnt solved the problem, now the h1 and the img/jetpackjpg move with the screen as I scroll

Comment: ive managed to get the h1 to stay in the correct position but its the img/jetpack.png found in my HTML that I cant seem to keep still as I scroll now, the logo is fine as it is